# Problems using SCP to copy files to a Server

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to send a directory under /home/inove-it/viewData to /home on my server. The server has a port defined so it is not running at port 22 as default, but when i put that argument it says that cannot find the directory 0192 when it is my port.

So here's what i am doing now:
`scp -r myuser@myserver:/home Documents/inoveit-projects/viewData -P 0192`.

Comment: How is this question related to Ubuntu? And the command is wrong anyway.

Comment: Look at this question and answer it will help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115560/use-scp-to-transfer-a-file-from-local-directory-x-to-remote-directory-y

Comment: Thanks Prince Kumar, your link just nailed it.

Comment: @Pilot6 i think that it is related to ubuntu. You can argue saying its for all unix universe but still including ubuntu. Sorry my english, i'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is wrong.

According to what you explained the command should look this way:

```
scp -r -P 192 /home/inove-it/viewData myuser@myserver:/home
```

Comment: that didint work. the link provided by Prince Kumar helped a lot.

Comment: And what is the difference from what is written there?

Comment: ```scp -P 2222 file.ext username@domain:~/ ``` you pass -P 192 after the destination directory and in my case it says ```192: No such file or directory```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but I changed it.

Comment: when i read the command manual it only shows the -P and doenst mention anything else.

Comment: `man scp` shows all the syntax.